# Getting number and pattern limit

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a pattern `i2`, 3 digits and followed by a dash `-` and 1 to 3 digits specifically.

Example data

```
i2123-1
i2121-20
i2111-331
i2111
i21111
i2111-1141
```

Should only match

```
i2123-1
i2121-20
i2111-331
```

I tried this but its not matching some patterns, and for some it matches too much.

```
preg_match_all('/i2\d{3}-\d{3}/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: `/i2\d{3}-\d{3}/` doesn't match `too much`, it matches the upper limit of digits after the '-'. It either matches or not, there is no too little or too much. If there are condition issues with `before` and `after` characters, they have to be specifically stated

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your last `\d{3}` to `\d{1,3}` to accept 1 to 3 numbers after the dash. But even then you will still match more than you want, I would use a word boundary `\b` for this specific case.

```
preg_match_all('/\bi2\d{3}-\d{1,3}\b/', $str, $matches);
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/dW4mN3)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the quantifier accept less using the `{m,n}` format and use a word boundary:

```
/i2\d{3}-\d{1,3}\b/
```

Or alternatively, a negative lookahead, or an anchor (if you don't want to match `i2123-123-`):

```
/i2\d{3}-\d{1,3}(?!.)/

/i2\d{3}-\d{1,3}$/
```

You'll probably need the multiline mode for the last one:

```
preg_match_all('/i2\d{3}-\d{1,3}$/m', $str, $matches);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lK5kQ4)

If you want to be absolutely sure there's nothing else in that pattern, use anchors and the multiline mode (if you additionally are testing multiple lines in a single string:

```
preg_match_all('/^i2\d{3}-\d{1,3}$/m', $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct solution need to include `\b` at the beginning of the pattern as well, so I would use

```
preg_match_all('/\bi2\d{3}-\d{1,3}\b/', $str, $matches);
```

Test this and other posted solutions against this sample input:

```
i2123-1
i2121-20
i2111-331
i2111
i21111
i2111-1141
 i2123-1
1i2121-20
ai2111-331
```

See this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xD3eN0).